# Reverse Proxy on cloudfront

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular site / web application (Lets call this **www.mysite.com**) hosted on Amazon S3 as a static website.

This s3 bucket serves as the origin for a cloudfront distribution and it works perfectly.

We have an additional requirement of deploying a blog for SEO purposes. I have wordpress instance which I mapped using DNS to **blog.mysite.com**

How can I make this **www.mysite.com/blog**

---

### Additional Requirements:

- All the links on the blog must redirect to www.mysite.com/blog instead of blog.mysite.com
- The address bar should always be displayed as www.mysite.com/blog
- All the guides I have gone through require the www.mysite.com to be hosted via Nginx or Apache. This has to be on S3 + cloudfront.

Thank You in advance.